# mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\login.php on line 10
> Error:

On executing the query

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","forms");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  
  $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM register Where username='$_POST[username]' AND password='$_POST[password]'");
  
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "login success";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is exposed to **SQL Injection**. Clean up input data first.

Comment: also, you called `mysqli_query()` twice. 2nd is incorrect & unnecessary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_fetch\_\* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: @0bijanmortazavi scroll down. I've given an answer long time ago (almost 3 years ago)

Answer (score 2):

`if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))` isn't good as `$sql` is an object, not a string

`$sql` is an object as `mysql_query`

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So you have not to do another `mysqli_query`, just modify your `if` in the following way

```
if(!$sql)
{
  //do something
}
```

This will work if you need to check query failures, otherwise it could return a `mysqli_result` even your query have returned 0 rows, so please pay attetion.

Comment: it's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

with

```
if($sql === FALSE)
```

By checking `$sql` is FALSE to prove the query is failed or not.

See : [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","forms");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql="SELECT * FROM register Where username='$_POST[username]' AND password='$_POST[password]'";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "login success";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Because you can execute a query ,It should be a string. But in your code

$sql=mysqli_query()

Returns an object to $sql

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM register Where username='".$_POST[username]."' AND password='."$_POST[password]."'";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

In your code you have already use the mysqli_query and you are passing the object of that in mysqli_query again.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM register Where username=\'' . $_POST[username]. '\' AND password=\''. $_POST[password].'\' ';
$response=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (empty( $response ))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Try this.